# How to Import MySqlDump File into MySQL without Selective Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having few large mysqldump files that i need to import to mysql on my desktop mysql server.Each dump file has only 1 table with multiple columns.I want to import on selective 2 columns as other columns are not required.

Currently i have been importing the dump using below stated commands, but this imports table with all columns.But i want to import only selective columns.

---

Create Database DatabaseName;

CONNECT DatabaseName

Show tables;

Source D:/DatabaseName

---

please suggest.

Comment: just copy dump file (to edit safely) and open with editor that can read big file, keep only parts what You need. (:  joking

Answer (score 6):

There are three ways you can go about this:

1. The easiest and fastest way to do this would be to first import the full dump, then drop the column(s) you don't want:

   ```
   mysql -u username -p password database_name < file_name.sql
   mysql -u username -p password database_name -e'ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name'
   ```
2. If the column you want to remove is very large, you can use `sed` to preemptively (and quickly) remove the offending column.  Something like this (the regex patterns will change based on the data you have in your table):

   ```
   # First, remove the column name from the INSERT line
   sed -i "s/`column_name`,//g" file_name.sql

   # Then, remove the column value from the VALUES lines
   sed -i "s/(\([0-9]+,'[\w+]',[0-9]+,)'.*',([0-9]+\),/\1\2/g" file_name.sql

   # Then, you can import your dump, entirely stripped of that column
   mysql -u username -p password database_name < file_name.sql
   ```

   - More about sed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed
   - More about regex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
3. If you have access to the DB the dump was made from, you can remove the column from a temp table before dumping:

   ```
   # First, create the temp table as a clone of your table, import the data
   mysql -u username -p password database_name -e 'CREATE TABLE table_name2 LIKE table_name; INSERT INTO table_name2 SELECT * FROM table_name; ALTER TABLE table_name2 DROP COLUMN column_name;'

   # Dump ONLY the temp table with the missing column
   mysqldump -u username -p password database_name table_name2 > dump_excluding_column.sql

   # Afterwards, delete the temporary table
   mysql -u username -p password database_name -e 'DROP TABLE table_name2;'
   ```

   When performing the import, you'll have to rename your table afterwards, e.g.:

   ```
   # Run the import
   mysql -u username -p password database_name < dump_excluding_column.sql

   # Afterwards, rename the table name to remove the "2" suffix
   mysql -u username -p password database_name -e 'RENAME TABLE table_name2 TO table_name;'
   ```

Comment: yea for simplicity

Comment: Sir,thank u for ure efforts, but the very reason i want to import only selective column is becz the size of dump files is very very large.Thus importing entire data and then deleting will be consuming more time.Plz refer to example i have given

Comment: Ok, then you can use `sed`.  I'll add a note below

Answer (score 0):

if You need dump with only necessary columns:

1) create temporary db
2) import dump
3) with some db gui or from console alter tables and keep necessary columns
4) backup resulting database

if You need to import directly to database only N olumns, so:

1) import dump 
2) with some db gui or from console alter tables and keep necessary columns

sooooooo... simple

Comment: Sir,thank u for ure efforts, but the very reason i want to import only selective column is becz the size of dump files is very very large.Thus importing entire data and then deleting will be consuming more time.Plz refer to example i have given

Comment: any other option ? as editing with db gui will be also consuming lot of time.

Comment: write script that will parse the dump file and remove out unnecessary things. there is no another way.